# JS Insert element from Object into script

Tags: javascript

My POS creates an object with the details of the current order as a way to pass these variables for use in other scripts, in this case, my affiliate tracker.

The question is, how do i call insert these elements in my affiliate tracker script?

The Object is:

```
<script>
  window.order = {"id":128131,"number":"GMIFZHW9XR84M2","total":"29.9","name":"Some Name"}
</script>
```

And a few lines down i have my affiliate tracker script

```
<div id='papSaleTrackingPlaceholder'></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(d,t) {
    var script = d.createElement(t); script.id= 'pap_x2s6df8d'; script.async = true;
    script.src = '//aff.ticket1.eu/scripts/d2f7zu4j0kx';
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var rs = this.readyState; if (rs && (rs != 'complete') && (rs != 'loaded')) return;

        PostAffTracker.setAccountId('default1');
var sale = PostAffTracker.createSale();
var obj = window.order;
console.log(window.order);
console.log(obj.total);
        sale.setTotalCost(obj.total);
        sale.setOrderID(obj.number);
        sale.setProductID('XXXXXX');
        sale.setCampaignID('a5b61064');

        try { PostAffTracker.track(); } catch (e) {}

    }
    var placeholder = document.getElementById('papSaleTrackingPlaceholder');
    placeholder.parentNode.insertBefore(script, placeholder);
    placeholder.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);
  })(document, 'script');
</script>
```

In my console log im getting all the properties correctly, but they are not being passed to the script. How do i pass the values from the obj into this:

```
   sale.setTotalCost('xxxx');
    sale.setOrderID('XXXX');
    sale.setProductID('XXXX');
```

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I see the problem here... `sale.setTotalCost(window.order.total);` and the same with the other methods should do it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if "window.order" exists when you are assigning it to the other object "obj".

If so, now you should be able to create the obj from window.order like so:

```
var obj = window.order
```

Now from "obj", you have access to all properties of window.order
You can check obj values with debug or simply with a console.log of obj.id; obj.total, etc...

Comment: window.order exists.

Comment: `console.log(obj.total); ` Gives me the right value on the console, but 
     `sale.setTotalCost = (obj.total);` wont work.

Comment: Have you tried this? 
You do not need to parse the window.order if it is already a Javascript object.  
By doing this, window.order is copied to "obj" and you can do whatever you want with the properties in it, like:  
`sale.setTotalCost(obj.total); 
// sale.setOrderID(obj.number); // ??? if this is the correct property 
// sale.setProductID(obj.id); // ??? if this is the correct property`

Comment: why not 
`sale.setTotalCost(obj.total);`
instead of 
`sale.setTotalCost = (obj.total);`

:D

Comment: This is my code right now:      `PostAffTracker.setAccountId('default1');
var sale = PostAffTracker.createSale();
var obj = window.order;
console.log(obj.total);
console.log(window.order)
        sale.setTotalCost(obj.total);`

The values are correct in the console log for obj.total and for window.order, but they dont appear in sales.setTotalCost, furthermore, my script requires that i pass them like ('value')

Comment: You are probably missing a step here, regarding the `PostAffTracker` object, or the `sale` 
Before`PostAffTracker.register();` how do you submit the data you created in `sale`? 
You should figure that out if it's not a code/bug issue. 
Good luck